# How do I use C API function PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords in Delphi?

Tags: python, c, delphi, python4delphi

I am currently writing a Python module using [python4delphi](https://code.google.com/p/python4delphi/). I would like to use the standard C API Function [PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords).

As you can see from the documentation the signature is so:

```c
int PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(PyObject *args, PyObject *kw, const char *format,
    char *keywords[], ...)
```

Now this function is not wrapped in python4delphi so I've added it by myself:

```delphi
PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords: function (args, kw: PPyObject; format: PAnsiChar; 
    keywords: array of PAnsiChar {;...}): Integer; cdecl varargs;
....
PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords := Import('PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords');
```

The problem I have is that I am getting an access violation error when I try to use it in way similar to this snippet:

```delphi
function PyScript_MyFunction(pself, args, keywds : PPyObject) : PPyObject; cdecl;
var
  AAA, BBB : PChar;
  kwlist : array[0..2] of PAnsiChar;
begin
  kwlist[0] := 'AAA';
  kwlist[1] := 'BBB';
  kwlist[2] := nil;

  BBB := 'BBB';
  with GetPythonEngine do
  begin
    if (PyErr_Occurred() = nil) and (PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, keywds,
        's|s:Script_MyFunction', kwlist, @AAA, @BBB) <> 0) then
    begin
      Result := VariantAsPyObject(MyFunction(AAA, BBB));
    end
    else
      Result := nil;
  end;
end;

//Module is my Python module I am working with

Module.AddMethodWithKeywords('Wrapped', @PyScript_MyFunction, 'no doc');
```

How can I fix this? Is there a way to debug such kind of errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your translation of the `keywords` parameter is incorrect. You've used a Delphi open array. A Delphi open array results in two things being passed, the index of the final item in the array, and the pointer to the first element of the array. Delphi open arrays are simply never to be used for interop.

You need to declare that parameter like so:

```
keywords: PPAnsiChar
```

That is a pointer to `PAnsiChar`.

Call the function like this:

```
PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(..., @kwlist[0], ...)
```

---

Personally I would use a dynamic array to prepare your parameter:

```
var
  kwlist: TArray<PAnsiChar>;
```

Initialise it like this:

```
kwlist := TArray<PAnsiChar>.Create('AAA', 'BBB', nil);
```

And pass it like this:

```
PPAnsiChar(kwlist)
```

or like this if you prefer:

```
@kwlist[0]
```

The latter is typesafe at least.

---

I note that you declared `AAA` and `BBB` to be of type `PChar`. Surely that should be `PAnsiChar`.

---

I'm far from sure that you've prepared all the other parameters correctly. I'm not familiar with this particular API call. For sure though, what I describe above is the first and most important problem to tackle.

I do wonder how you the caller are expected to deallocate the strings that are returned to you? I presume that you are expected to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, it works now. I am not sure, what strings should I deallocate and why?

Comment: Well, `AAA`, `BBB` are being modified. The function is returning `PAnsiChar` values into those variables. Does the memory behind those null terminated strings need to be deallocated? Perhaps not. Perhaps they are just pointers to existing memory. I cannot tell and the docs are really rather poor.